# Sharing an audio file from resources in Kotlin android app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, android-resources

I have an app that has mp3 audio files in the res/raw folder. I want to be able to share these audio files with messaging apps like Signal.

Currently, my code to share the audio file is as follows:

```
val sendIntent = Intent()
sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.packageName + "/" + R.raw.my_audio_resource))
sendIntent.type = "audio/*"
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))
```

Now, it seems like the file itself is being shared, however, the filename becomes some numerical identifier (e.g. "2131739427") without the correct extension (".mp3"). I assume that this causes Signal not to accept the file, as I receive the following error message when I share it with Signal:

```
Multiple attachments are only supported for images and videos
```

I think the solution would be to share the file with the correct extension, but I do not know how I can alter the name of the resource when it's being shared.

Comment: I dont believe you can share a file from resource in this way . `Now, it seems like the file itself is being shared,`

Comment: @blackapps I have this app called Video Transcoder (protect.videoeditor). When I share it with this app, it correctly opens the audio file.

Comment: Few apps will honor an `android.resource` `Uri` in `EXTRA_STREAM`. That's in part because the documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM` points out that it needs to be a `content` `Uri`.